# magento 2.1 how to switch to default design "luma" or "blank"?

Tags: magento-2.1

I have installed custom theme in magento and need to check working of fuctionality inside clean magento.

But I couldn't find how to change design.

At the image attached you can see "Search Robots" configuration, but before there was themes switching.

Where did they gone? Or is that magento bug?

[image]

Comment: It seems the theme location has moved and can now be found under Content > Design > Configuration, is it showing there for you? (I don't have my own Magento 2.1 setup to look at.)

Comment: @kb., you are right, thanx. You can post your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Magento 2.1 they moved the theme settings, it can now be found in admin under:

`Content > Design > Configuration`